# Error during compilation : twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am learning playframework. I am using plaframework 2.5. Getting the below error :

object twitterBootstrap is not a member of package views.html.helper

Code :

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
@main("Product form") {
<h1>Product form</h1>
@helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
<fieldset>
<legend>Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("New"))</legend>
@helper.inputText(productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
@helper.inputText(productForm("name"),'_label -> "Name")
@helper.textarea(productForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
<a class="btn" href="@routes.Products.index()">Cancel</a>
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Play bootstrap integration was not keeping up to speed with Twitter Bootstrap, and was removed.  The best Bootstrap integration is

https://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/

Generally, if you take out '@import helper.twitterBootstrap._' line then it will work fine.